# How to retrieve mobilenos stored in Sqlite database and store in a List<String> variable using Flutter android app

Tags: sqlite, flutter, android-studio, data-retrieval

Please help me to retrieve mobilenos stored in Sqlite database and store in a List variable using Flutter android app. I am a beginner, please help! My obective is to fetched stored mobile nos to a variable and send sms to those mobile nos.

```
Future<List<Contact>> getMobiles() async {
     var dbClient = await db;
    List<Map> maps = await dbClient.rawQuery('SELECT mobileno FROM contacts');
    List<Contact> contacts = [];
      if (maps.length > 0) {
          for (int i = 0; i < maps.length; i++) {
          contacts.add(Contact.fromMap(maps[i]));
      }
    }
    return contacts;

  }
```

```
My (contact_model.dart) I have added codes like below
```

```
class Contact {
  int id;
  String mobileno;
  Contact(this.id, this.mobileno);

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
      var map = <String, dynamic>{
         'id': id,
         'mobileno': mobileno,
    };
    return map;
  }

  Contact.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
        id = map['id'];
        mobileno = map['mobileno'];
  }
  @override
  String toString(){
    return 'Contact{id:$id,mobileno:$mobileno}';
  }
}
```

My Home Screen (HomeScreen.dart)

```
class HomePageState extends State<HomePage>{
    String _message, _location;
    Future<List<Contact>> contacts;
    Position _currentPosition;
    DBHelper dbHelper;
    @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
      dbHelper = DBHelper();

     refreshContactNoList();
    
    }
      refreshContactNoList() async{
      setState(() {
      contacts = dbHelper.getMobiles();

      });
    }

    _sendSMS() async {
    
   List<String> recipents=refreshContactNoList();

      try {
        String _result = await sendSMS(
            message: 'Please Help!!!',recipients:recipents);
        setState(() => _message = _result);
        print("SMS is sent!");
        print(recipents);
       } catch (error) {
        setState(() => _message = error.toString());
      }
}
```

My obective is to fetched stored mobile nos to a variable and send sms to those mobile nos.

I am currently getting the following error,
`Unhandled Exception: type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast`

Comment: What is your current issue?

Comment: My obective is to fetched stored mobile nos to a list variable and send sms to those mobile nos. But it shows following error: Unhandled Exception: type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast